# How to post image and message combinely to friends wall using friends facebook id

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to post on multiple friends wall using their facebook ids](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13646861/how-to-post-on-multiple-friends-wall-using-their-facebook-ids)

I want to post (image+message)or sometimes message only to friends wall by using friends facebook id.

Is it possible to do this by using facebook sdk or graph api?

The actual requirement I got is, I have some of my friends facebook id's and I want to post on their wall by using their facebook ids.

How can I fulfill this requirement?

Any ideas.

Thanks in advance

Comment: if you have there own id pass word then you can everything.

Comment: I am talking about how to post programatically.

Comment: i think you want to uplaod image+message on multiple id on his own wall so how can you do without user pass in programmatic ?

Answer (score 0):

"picture"  variable to a wall, it posts a pic from a URL but you can change it to

```
 protected void postPicToWall(String userID, String msg, String caption, String picURL){
        try {
            if (isSession()) {
                String response = mFacebook.request((userID == null) ? "me" : userID);

                Bundle params = new Bundle();
                params.putString("message", msg);  
                params.putString("caption", caption);
                params.putString("picture", picURL);

                response = mFacebook.request(((userID == null) ? "me" : userID) + "/feed", params, "POST");       

                Log.d("Tests",response);
                if (response == null || response.equals("") || 
                        response.equals("false")) {
                    Log.v("Error", "Blank response");
                }
            } else {
                // for relogin 
                Log.d(TAG, "sessionNOTValid, relogin");
                mFacebook.authorize(this, PERMS, new LoginDialogListener());
            }
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: I am asking about posting to friends wall not on users wall