# How to post on multiple friends wall using their facebook ids

Tags: android, facebook

In my application, I have a requirement of posting image and message to wall of multiple friends.

I have seen stackoverflow posts regarding this issue.I found that there is a need of Batch Requests concept to do this.

I cant understand, how can I create jsonobjects.

I have seen in some of the posts,that we cannot post more than 10 posts at a time.I didnt have much idea on this Batch Request concept.

Comment: I hope you are aware that posting to a friend’s wall through the API will not be possible any more after Feb. 6 2013 – https://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/#february-2013

Answer (score 1):

you can use the following code to create delay between successive requests.

```
    int count = 10;
    new Timer().schedule(new TimerTask() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            if (count>=10) {
                this.cancel();
            }

        MainActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

            public void run() {
                //Do the facebook request.

            }
        });

        }
    }, 1000 , 1000);
```

Comment: How to create a json data ,I have only facebook ids of my friends

Comment: The image byte data or what data you want to create?